# Sharing types & endpoints between frontend & backend

Tags: design, architecture, api, json

I'm looking for a clean solution to share types, endpoints and response format between a backend and frontend. The backend will be in Python & the frontend in Typescript. The backend is a REST API.

Ideally, we will have a code & architecture as follow :

```
 - backend/
   - ...
 - frontend/
   - ...
 - config/
   - types/
     - frontend.json
     - backend.json
     - shared.json
   - endpoints.json
```

The .json files would be used to generate some language specific types or variables using a cli or any converting tool ([quicktype for example](https://github.com/quicktype/quicktype)).

Is there a better approach to tackle this ? Any idea is greatly welcomed !

Comment: Have you looked at https://openapi-generator.tech?

Comment: @JamesMcLeod thanks for your answer. It seems very complete and rather complicate for the purpose I chase. But I will definitely have a look at OpenAPI format and tools, seems awesome !

Comment: I thought that at first too. But using OpenAPi should be a no-brainer since it is a convenient and standardized way to describe a REST API, and the using the code generator is only a bit more work.

Comment: try this : https://www.transcrypt.org/

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a better approach to tackle this ? Any idea is greatly welcomed !

Depending on your use-case there may be better ways.

1. If you have 1 (web) frontend for your backend, then this separation through an API might make no sense in the first place. By introducing an indirection/abstraction, you'll just generate more work and make the whole thing less maintainable.
2. If you want to have fancy javascript effects and no-refresh things in the web, you can do that without introducing a specific API. Look at Wicket (Java) for example. They introduce a generic partial update functionality and just re-use that to do all the fancy stuff.
3. If you really-really want to have a REST API for whatever reason, sharing artifacts might still not be the best way. Instead of generating representations from scratch on the client, in REST the server could provide **forms** (just like with HTML) which the client just fills out and submits. This would be *more* RESTful and also much easier, and there would be nothing to be shared.

There are probably a lot more options that are better before you should consider things like sharing code or using Swagger/OpenAPI. It always depends on your exact requirements of course.